# How to make two apps with same code base in React native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a client side app and i want to make vendor side with same code. As i have to just change some screens on vendor side. But when i install it, OS register both apps as same. And sees vendor side as an update which overwrites client side app when installed on same device. What i have to change so OS register both apps as different? I've tried changing package name in `AndroidMenifest.xml`, `MainActivity.java` and `MainApplication.java`. But it was still replaced instead of installing as a seperate app.

client side files:
AndroidManifest
`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.saloon">`

MainActivity
`package com.saloon;`
MainApplication
`package com.saloon;`

Vendor side files:
AndroidManifest
`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.saloonvendor">`

MainActivity
`package com.saloonvendor;`
MainApplication
`package com.saloonvendor;`

Comment: Hi Muhammad. How did you handled it ? Any help please. I want to make 2 apps out of same codebase. 1 app is already running but other I need to configure with different app icon and endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the Bundle ID for iOS and the package name for android.

Comment: i've changed package name, but it did not worked

Comment: How did you change it?

Comment: try also to chnage android/app/build.gradle: applicationId "MY.APP.NEW_ID" In android/app/BUCK: android_build_config( package="MY.APP.NEW_ID" ) android_resource( package="MY.APP.NEW_ID" ) Gradle' cleaning in the end (in /android folder): ./gradlew clean

Comment: it worked. what about ios?

Comment: just chnage Bundle ID

Comment: i'm newbie. can u tell where? like u told in android

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UN9Uwhz6bBo